# Can't connect to Bluetooth Peripheral from Background in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth

I manage to successfully connect and pair with peripheral when in foreground. But when I try to connect from background, peripheral gets connected and then immediately disconnected with the following errors:

```
BTServer[67] <Error>: LE pairing failed to device "F90..." with result 1

BTServer[67] <Error>: ATT no characteristic values with UUID 0x2A00 could be read in range [0x0001, 0x0007] on device "F90..."

BTServer[67] <Error>: Aborting command as device "F90..." is no longer connected
```

It seems strange because peripheral is already paired and nothing like that happens when application in foreground.

This only happens on iOS 8. On iOS 7 the same code works fine both in background and foreground modes.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to solve it?